# Delphi7. Read BLOB field with WideString data in it

Tags: database, unicode, delphi-7

Can anybody help? I'm keeping an old Delphi7 project and have next trouble. How can I store BLOB field value if it contains Unicode string?
I tried:

```
var
  str: WideString;
begin
  ...
  str := WideString(Fields[1].AsString); - but I get empty string
  ...

  ...
  str := VarToWideStr(Fields[1].AsVariant); - but I get "(BLOB)" result in str varible.
  ...
end;
```

My solution:
Code usage:

```
...
stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  Fields[1].SaveToStream(stream);
  ss := MemStreamToWStr(stream);
finally
  stream.Destroy;
end;
...
```

And function:

```
function TSnsFrame.MemStreamToWStr(Mstream: TMemoryStream): WideString;
begin
  Mstream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
  SetLength(Result, Mstream.size div 2);
  MStream.ReadBuffer(Result[1], Mstream.size);
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `TDataSet.CreateBlobStream()`.  It returns a `TStream` that can be used to read/write the raw data of a blob field.

Comment: I used SaveToStream to save data to stream and then created Treader and try to read WideString. But i'm getting error when setting stream.position := 0;

Comment: Please update your question with the latest code you are using.